# How can I simulate mobile devices and debug in Firefox Browser?

Tags: firefox, mobile, plugins

I would like to be able to view and debug my website in mobile device mode on a computer. Also I want to debug my website with tools like Firebug or ... even better I can use Firebug.
What is an established solution to do that?

Comment: I just want to add that this is a native feature in Chrome. You can choose `Galaxy S5` simulation, then reload the page to view it as so, for example.

Answer (score 54):

You can use tools own browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome...) to debug your JavaScript.

As for resizing, Firefox/Chrome has own resources accessible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> OR <kbd>F12</kbd>. Going tab "style editor" and clicking "adaptive/responsive design" icon.

Old Firefox versions

[image: Old Firefox]

New Firefox/Firebug

[image: Firefox]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

*Another way is to install an addon like "Web Developer"

Comment: I think firebug is struggling to keep up with firefox these days.  I love it, but it's struggling.  More and more, I use the built-in inspector that ships with Firefox when I have to troubleshoot Firefox.

Comment: device emulation is so unreliable tho

Answer (score 33):

Use the Responsive Design Tool using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Responsive mode is not the same as mobile simulation

Comment: A huge difference is that the Responsive Design Tool doesn't show a virtual keyboard like on mobile. That omission can affect the layout of a mobile website.

Answer (score 16):

Most web applications detects mobile devices based on the HTTP Headers.

If your web site also uses HTTP Headers to identify mobile device, you can do the following:

1. Add Modify Headers plug in to your Firefox browser (
   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/
   )
2. Using plugin modify headers:

   - select Headers tab-> select Action 'ADD'
   - to simulate e.g. iPhone add a header with name `User-Agent` and value: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3`
   - click 'Add' button
3. After that you should be able to see mobile
   version of you web application in Firefox and use Firebug plugin.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 12):

You could use the Firefox add-on [User Agent Overrider](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/). With this add-on you can use whatever user agent you want, for examlpe:

```
Firefox 28/Android: Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:28.0) Gecko/24.0 Firefox/28.0
```

If your website detects mobile devices through the user agent then you can test your layout this way.

---

Update Nov '17:

Due to the release of Firefox 57 and the introduction of web extension this add-on sadly is no longer available. Alternatively you can edit the Firefox preference `general.useragent.override` in your configuration:

1. In the address bar type `about:config`
2. Search for `general.useragent.override`
3. If the preference doesn't exist, right-click on the about:config page, click New, then select String
4. Name the new preference general.useragent.override
5. Set the value to the user agent you want

Comment: Really good to use. It remind me there are similar extensions in chrome, eg:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Comment: Thanks!! That's what I wanted, but the problem is this affects all browser tabs :(

Comment: Not compatible with Firefox Quantum

Comment: @JWiley That's what I've said in my _Update Nov '17_ ;)

Answer (score 6):

I would use the "Responsive Design View" available under Tools -> Web Developer -> Responsive Design View. It will let you test your CSS against different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the already mentioned built in **Responsive Design Mode** (via dev tools) for setting customised screen sizes together with the [Random Agent Spoofer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/random-agent-spoofer/) Plugin  to modify your headers to simulate you are using Mobile, Tablet etc. Many websites specify their content according to these identified headers.

As dev tools you can use the built in Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> for Mac) which have become quite similar to Chrome dev tools by now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use the chrome toggle device toolbar with the chrome inspector. It provides you a user agent switch along with responsive mode. 
[image]